# FragSize in solr works to handle characters, Is there any property that works for words?

Tags: solr, solrnet

In below code, Fragsize is controlling characters count, Is there a way or property to control number of words in SOLR highlighting returned results?

```
new QueryOptions()
                {
                    Highlight = new HighlightingParameters()
                    {
                        Fragsize = 100,
                        AfterTerm = "</em>",
                        BeforeTerm = "<em>",
                        Fields = new List<string>() { "Contents"},
                        Snippets = 5
                    }
```